# Keep exact value with Python's math?

Tags: python

With Python's [`math` library](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html), an expression for an irrational number like

```
math.sin(math.pi/3)
```

will return a decimal approximation.

I've been looking at the documentation for a way to keep it at the exact value (i.e. returning `sqrt(3)/2` instead of `0.8660254037844386`), but I haven't found anything. I'm pretty new to Python, so I apologize if I missed it.

Comment: By exact value do you mean math.sin(math.pi/3) as expected result?

Comment: the moment you write `sqrt(3)/2` at the right-hand-side of an assignment statement, it will get substituted by the value that Python calculates for it.

Comment: You can take a look at SymPy: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html#what-is-symbolic-computation

Comment: `sqrt(3)/2` isn't an exact value, it is an expression that will be evaluated to some value (in this case, the decimal approximation). It *looks* like you want a computer algebra system.

Comment: Why is it that a decimal approximation won't do? Do you just need to delay evaluation for some time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbolic mathematics is not something that most general-purpose programming languages do. Python works with integers and (real and complex) floating point values. For example the symbol `math.pi` is not a representation of the mathematical constant π, but just a Python variable containing a finite-precision floating point approximation of π.

However, some people do sometimes want to do symbolic mathematics, so tools exist as third-party libraries. For example, you can do symbolic maths in Python by installing the [SymPy package](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
import sympy
sympy.sqrt(sympy.pi/3)
#> sqrt(pi)/3
```